# add specific rows on pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to transform a python notebook in pyspark pipeline and I'm blocked by... it seems a simple problem ....

I have this dataframe after a count aggregation group By Id:

```
| Id |  count |
| 0  |   5    |
| 1  |   3    |
| 4  |   6    |
```

And I want this :

```
| Id |  count |
| 0  |   5    |
| 1  |   3    |
| 2  |   0    |
| 3  |   0    |
| 4  |   6    |
| 5  |   0    |
```

I have tried to add a [0,1,3,4,5] array in each rows, then explode outter this array, then tried to find a way to keep the rows I need but it's seems a bit complicated for this simple case.

DO you have any tips ?
Thx in advance

Comment: How come the max id is 5?

Comment: Yeah I I should have specified in my case the max it's always 5, it's my use case .

Comment: If that's such a small dataframe, why not convert to Pandas, transform it then convert it back to Spark Dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

```
original.show()
+---+-----+
| id|count|
+---+-----+
|  1|   12|
|  3|   15|
+---+-----+


df = spark.createDataFrame([(0,0),(1,0),(2,0),(3,0),(4,0),(5,0)],['id', 'default_count'])
df.show()
+---+-------------+
| id|default_count|
+---+-------------+
|  0|            0|
|  1|            0|
|  2|            0|
|  3|            0|
|  4|            0|
|  5|            0|
+---+-------------+

result=original.join(df, on='id', how='right').withColumn('count', F.coalesce(F.col('count'), F.col('default_count'))).orderBy(F.col('id')).drop(F.col('default_count'))

+---+-----+
| id|count|
+---+-----+
|  0|    0|
|  1|   12|
|  2|    0|
|  3|   15|
|  4|    0|
|  5|    0|
+---+-----+
```

Answer (score -2):

```py
df.show()

+---+-----+
| Id|count|
+---+-----+
|  0|    5|
|  1|    3|
|  4|    6|
+---+-----+

extra_rows = spark.createDataFrame([(2, 0),
                       (3, 0),
                       (5, 0)],
                      ['Id', 'count'])

df.unionByName(extra_rows).orderBy('Id').show()

+---+-----+
| Id|count|
+---+-----+
|  0|    5|
|  1|    3|
|  2|    0|
|  3|    0|
|  4|    6|
|  5|    0|
+---+-----+
```

Comment: hmm didn't work, it's just an example.
I could have this : 
```
| Id |  count |
| 3 |   15    |

```
And in that case i want this : 
```
| Id |  count |
| 0  |   0    |
| 1  |   0    |
| 2  |   0    |
| 3  |   15    |
| 4  |   0   |
| 5  |   0    |
```

Comment: the output is exactly the one you asked for, if that didn't work your doing something wrong

Comment: Are you just looking to have a row for id 1- specific number with no gaps so you want to fill it with the missing ID and count 0